# Customizing Django forms with RadioSelect widget

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

So I'm using jQuery UI to [skin the radio buttons](http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#radio) but I can't get Django to render my form the way it has to be done.

I need to have this structure:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><label for="notify_new_friends">Notify when new friends join</label></td>
        <td class="radio">
            <input type="radio" name="notify_new_friends" id="notify_new_friends_immediately" value="1" checked="checked"/><label for="notify_new_friends_immediately">Immediately</label>
            <input type="radio" name="notify_new_friends" id="notify_new_friends_never" value="0"/><label for="notify_new_friends_never">Never</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

So to summarize that I need the radio buttons within a class (radio) where they have an `input` and a `label for`.

When I render the form in my template with `{{ profile_form.notify_new_friends }}` I get the following:

```
<ul>
    <li><label for="id_notify_new_friends_0"><input type="radio" id="id_notify_new_friends_0" value="0" name="notify_new_friends" /> Immediately</label></li>
    <li><label for="id_notify_new_friends_1"><input type="radio" id="id_notify_new_friends_1" value="1" name="notify_new_friends" /> Never</label></li>
</ul>
```

Which is exactly what I want except for the list-part. So I tried looping over it which gives me the labels formatted differently:

```
{% for item in profile_form.notify_new_friends %}
    {{ item }}
{% endfor %}
```

which gives me:

```
<label><input type="radio" name="notify_new_friends" value="0" /> Immediately</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="notify_new_friends" value="1" /> Never</label>
```

So the problem here is that it stops using `label for` and starts using just `label` to wrapp it all with.

I also tried doing something like this, but then the `label` and `label_tag` don't render anything.

```
{{ profile_form.notify_new_friends.0 }}
{{ profile_form.notify_new_friends.0.label_tag }}
{{ profile_form.notify_new_friends.0.label }}
```

*So does anyone know how I can render this properly!?*

FYI, this is my forms.py:

```
self.fields['notify_new_friends'] = forms.ChoiceField(label='Notify when new friends join', widget=forms.RadioSelect, choices=NOTIFICATION_CHOICES)
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#radioselect - did you read this ?

Comment: @AlexanderA.Sosnovskiy yes, but I had missed the `choice_label` to get the label title, but unfortunately doing `{{ radio.tag }}` does not provide me with an ID and therefore I can not do `label for` which I need to do.

Comment: field id's are auto generated try, {{ field.auto_id }}

Comment: @ArgsKwargs I might have misunderstood how to use it, but no, that doesn't give me anything rendered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it doesn't seem to be a good way to do this I chose to rearrange the generated code using jQuery.

```
// First remove the ul and li tags
$('.radio ul').contents().unwrap();
$('.radio li').contents().unwrap();
// Then move the input to outside of the label
$('.radio > label > input').each(function() {
    $(this).parent().before(this);
});
// Then apply the jQuery UI buttonset
$( ".radio" ).buttonset();
```

This made it go from:

```
<ul>
    <li><label for="id_notify_new_friends_0"><input type="radio" id="id_notify_new_friends_0" value="0" name="notify_new_friends" /> Immediately</label></li>
    <li><label for="id_notify_new_friends_1"><input type="radio" id="id_notify_new_friends_1" value="1" name="notify_new_friends" /> Never</label></li>
</ul>
```

to:

```
<input type="radio" id="id_notify_new_friends_0" value="0" name="notify_new_friends" /><label for="id_notify_new_friends_0"> Immediately</label></li>
<input type="radio" id="id_notify_new_friends_1" value="1" name="notify_new_friends" /><label for="id_notify_new_friends_1"> Never</label></li>
```

and my jQuery UI styling works fine.

Comment: I think if there is possiblities to do it without javascript, we should avoid js... Especially on page loading - worse performance, worse SEO. If we use javascript to manipulation, it should be dynamical manipulation which cause so reason like interaction.

Comment: I don't believe a JavaScript that simply rearranges the same content on the page is likely to affect SEO.  That aside, this solution potentially works very well in the Django admin, where SEO is irrelevant and controlling the HTML output would require overriding multiple Django classes as mentioned in tnajdek's answer.

Answer (score 11):

In my code I discovered that changing the widget from

```
forms.RadioSelect
```

to

```
forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'id': 'value'})
```

magically causes the resulting `tag` value to include the `id` attribute with the index of the item appended. If you use

```
{% for radio in form.foo %}
    <li>
        {{ radio }}
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

in the form you get a `label` wrapped around an `input`. If you want the more conventional `input` followed by `label`, you need to do this:

```
{% for radio in form.value %}
    <li>
        {{ radio.tag }}
        <label for="value_{{ forloop.counter0 }}">{{ radio.choice_label }}</label>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: What if i want to add certain attribute to the **input radio button**

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately this is more complicated than it should be, it seems you need to override at least 2 classes: `RadioRenderer` and `RadioInput`. The following should help you get started but you might need to tweak it a little.

First create a custom radio button input widget. The only purpose of us overriding the render method is to get rid of annoying structure Django enforces (`<label><input /></label>`) where instead we want ours (`<label /><input />`):

```
class CustomRadioInput(RadioInput):
    def render(self, name=None, value=None, attrs=None, choices=()):
        name = name or self.name
        value = value or self.value
        attrs = attrs or self.attrs
        if 'id' in self.attrs:
            label_for = ' for="%s_%s"' % (self.attrs['id'], self.index)
        else:
            label_for = ''
            choice_label = conditional_escape(force_unicode(self.choice_label))
            return mark_safe(u'%s<label%s>%s</label>' % (self.tag(), label_for, choice_label))
```

Now we need to override `RadioRenderer` in order to:

1. Force it to use our custom radio input widget
2. Remove `<li>` wraping every single input field and `<ul>` wrapping all input fields:

Something along these lines should do:

```
class RadioCustomRenderer(RadioFieldRenderer):
    def __iter__(self):
        for i, choice in enumerate(self.choices):
            yield CustomRadioInput(self.name, self.value, self.attrs.copy(), choice, i)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        choice = self.choices[idx]
        return CustomRadioInput(self.name, self.value, self.attrs.copy(), choice, idx)

    def render(self):
        return mark_safe(u'%s' % u'\n'.join([u'%s' % force_unicode(w) for w in self]))
```

Finally instruct Django to use custom renderer

```
notify_new_friends = forms.ChoiceField(label='Notify when new friends join', widget=forms.RadioSelect(renderer=RadioCustomRenderer), choices=NOTIFICATION_CHOICES)
```

**Please bear in mind:** This now outputs radio buttons together with encompassing `<td>` hence you need to build a table around it in your template, something along these lines:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="{{field.auto_id}}">{{field.label}}</label></td>
    <td>{{ field.errors }} {{field}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I agree, the documentation for this is lacking imo. And while I agree with most of the Django documentation, examples of html forms using the shell are not the best approach.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone stumble upon this problem and just want to render the radio button without ul: they should follow this link.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/widgets/#selector-widgets

Example below.

```
{% for radio in myform.beatles %}
    <div class="myradio">
    {{ radio }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Finally, I have found the answer! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try like this ,  I got it..

from django.forms.widgets import RadioFieldRenderer
from django.utils.encoding import force_unicode
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe


class RadioCustomRenderer( RadioFieldRenderer ):
    def render( self ):
        return  mark_safe(u'%s' % u'\n'.join([u'%s'  % force_unicode(w) for w in self]))

in form

widgets = {
            'validity': forms.RadioSelect(renderer=RadioCustomRenderer),
        }
```