# Remove bullet points in RadioSelect Widget in django

Tags: python, django, forms, widget

I have a form that inherits from a model in Django that is rendered with a RadioSelect widget.
I would like to remove the bullet points.

Mi form is like this:

```
class FormFromModel(forms.ModelForm):
    c1 = [(1, 'Answer 1'), (2, 'Ans2'), (3, 'Ans3'), (4, 'Ans4'), ]
    q1 = forms.IntegerField(label='Question.... ?',
                            widget=forms.RadioSelect(choices=c1), initial=4)
```

And in the HTML I'm doing:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><b> 1. {{Inputs.q1.label}}</b></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> {{Inputs.q1}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I have something like:

[What currently have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aylzk.png)

And I will like:

[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KctwV.png)

Any help is appreciated, Thanks

Comment: I found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63938822/7806269